# « J'ai rêvé que... » passé composé ou plus-que-parfait ?

Tags: grammaire, concordance-des-temps

Dans l'expression:

> J'ai rêvé que…

Est-ce qu'on peut employer le passé composé pour exprimer une action que l'on a fait durant un rêve:

> J'ai rêvé que je suis sorti…

Ou bien faut-il employer le plus-que-parfait dans ce cas :

> J'ai rêvé que j'étais sorti…

?

Comment: Il faut utiliser l'imparfait: *J'ai rêvé que je sortais*

Answer (score 5):

Tout dépend de la règle de concordance des temps entre la proposition principale (ici: rêver) et la subordonnée (ici: sortir).

Si la subordonnée est :

antérieure → plus que parfait :

> J'ai rêvé que j'étais sorti

simultanée → imparfait de l'indicatif :

> J'ai rêvé que je sortais

postérieure → présent du conditionnel :

> J'ai rêvé que je sortirais

Le passé composé n'est pas conforme à cette règle, il est donc incorrect de dire :

> J'ai rêvé que je <s>suis sorti</s>

Answer (score 1):

Les deux sont possibles.

> J'ai rêvé que je suis sorti ...

Avec cette forme, l'action de sortir se passe dans le rêve. Le récit peut s'arrêter là.

> J'ai rêvé que j'étais sorti ...

Avec cette forme, l'action de sortir est arrivée avant ce qui se passe dans le rêve. Un récit supplémentaire est attendu.

Comment: Je refléchis et je ne vois aucun exemple de phrase complète ou *J'ai rêvé que je suis sorti" serait naturel en racontant un rêve.

Answer (score -1):

Les deux sont possibles, mais il est plus courant d'employer le plus que parfait dans ce cas.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sur que "j'ai révé que je suis" soit correct. Il me semble que c'est une faute (même si certaines personnes font la faute...). Cela me fait le même effet que "Si j'aurai su..."